# Error Parsing /index.xhtml: not supported setting property http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler

Tags: spring, jsf-2, jboss

I am trying to build a project using JSF, JPA, Spring, but I am not able to succeed. I am using JBoss as my server. It shows no error, but shows 404 error. Interesting thing is that when I use Tomcat, then the console is clear, but on loading page it shows,

> Error Parsing /index.xhtml: not supported setting property http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler

Here's the complete stack trace

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /index.xhtml: not supported setting property http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:425)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:408)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.metadataCompile(Compiler.java:130)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:327)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$200(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:164)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:143)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:260)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:209)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:233)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>Jsf_Spring_Jpa</display-name>

     <!-- Welcome Page -->
   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- JSF Servlet is defined to container -->
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <!-- Mapping with servlet and url for the http requests. -->

  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <!-- Spring Context Configuration' s Path definition -->
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value> /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>

   <!-- Project Stage Level -->
   <context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
     <param-value>Development</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <!-- The Bootstrap listener to start up and shut down Spring's root WebApplicationContext. It is registered to Servlet Container -->
   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

    <listener>
         <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: @BalusC: Ok, i got it. I didn't know it before.

Comment: hey, tried to deploy project on weblogic 9.2 got **ModuleException**  
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Unmarshaller failed. It also shows **com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to load java type corresponding to e=web-app@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee**

Answer (score 8):

This error comes from `pull-parser` which is an optional dependency of `dom4j`. You might be inadvertently getting pull-parser on your classpath even though it's optional for dom4j. Try explicitly excluding it and using your JDK's built-in parser instead (e.g. `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser`) which it should do by default then.

This question is 6 years old, so the following cannot have been the problem, but: in my Gradle project upgrading from Gradle 5.4 to Gradle 6.5 suddenly resulted in `pull-parser` being on the classpath because of a dependency on `dom4j` even though, as mentioned, the dependency of `dom4j` on `pull-parser` is optional and previously that wasn't happening. I've reported this to the Gradle project: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13656.

Comment: Thanks for the additional hint with Gradle. This was exactly my problem, too.

Answer (score 7):

I get rid of the error by adding following dependency (in Gradle syntax):

```
implementation 'pull-parser:pull-parser:2.1.10'
```

Comment: This worked for me. Kotlin spring boot, InteliJ